# subset (slice) of pandas.DataFrame has the same index as the original DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose, I have a DataFrame with MultiIndex like this:

```
In [1]:d=pnd.DataFrame(range(5),index=pnd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A',1),('A',2),('A',3),('A',4),('A',5)]))

In [2]: d
Out[2]: 
     0
A 1  0
  2  1
  3  2
  4  3
  5  4
```

I can create another DataFrame by subsetting:

```
In [3]: p=d.loc[('A',slice(1,3)),:].copy()

In [4]: p
Out[4]: 
     0
A 1  0
  2  1
  3  2
```

but the index object of this new DataFrame is the same as from the original DataFrame (contains all original items in the 'levels').

```
In [5]: p.index
Out[5]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'A'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2]])
```

How do I copy-out a subset which does not 'remember' the index object of the original DataFrame?

The reason I need to this is because some of my functions access the index object to get metadata, and the fact that the index carries over form the original DataFrame confuses these functions.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the top level of your index in your subset, you can set

```
p.index = p.index.droplevel()
p.index
Int64Index([1, 2, 3], dtype='int64')
```

Alternatively if you want to keep the multi-index and just reset the levels you can call `set_levels`:

```
p.index = p.index.set_levels(p.index.droplevel(),1)
p.index
MultiIndex(levels=[['A'], [1, 2, 3]],
       labels=[[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2]])
```

Comment: Thanks! I suppose the latter solution will work, since I want to keep the top level. But it seems inelegant because the top level label have to be mentioned explicitly as an argument to set_levels.

Comment: So, this latter solution works if I subset based on the second level. What about subsetting on the first level?

Comment: I ended up creating the new index explicitly and then assigning it to the subset. There must be more natural solution to this problem!